# Custom UITableViewCell - set image to be cells height

Tags: uitableview

I create a UIImageView inside a custom UITableViewCell. I want to set the height of the UImageView to match the height of the cell but I cannot get it right. I do not want to hard code a value. I have tried;

```
self.imageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, self.frame.size.height)];
```

And

```
self.imageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, self.contentView.frame.size.height)];
```

I thought this would set the image to be the height of the cell, but it is not the same height.

My cell height is a custom height of 80.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all "imageView" is a reserved property of UITableViewCell. You can't use it if you want to add your own UIImageView.

I suppose you are not using auto layout in your project. So just add autoresizing mask to your image view.

```
self.yourImageView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, self.contentView.bounds.size.height)];
self.yourImageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Comment: Yup this worked. You are right, imageView is a reserved word, I was merely using it in the example. Thank you for your help.